# ScrollViewer doesn't work on Surface 4 - WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer, mahapps.metro

I am creating an application in WPF ( C # ).
And here's my problem, when the test on the surface 4 , with the stylus the ScrollViewer does not work , that does not scroll .
But it is clear that if I try with your finger , the finger works . It ' possible that the surface pen should be treated differently from windows? how can I fix this small , but huge problem ?
Here is my code , it works with your finger scroll , with the surface 4 no pen. Help :)

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="listPastMeetinsVisibility" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="15,36,15,35" Background="GhostWhite" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" PanningMode="Both">
          <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PastMeetingList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <surface:SurfaceButton Tag="{Binding MID}" Click="Meeting_Click">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <StackPanel>                        
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="118"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderBrush="#DDD" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"></Border>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="28" Margin="20,5,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource Lato-Semibold}" Text="{Binding PastDayString}"/>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding PastMonthString}" FontSize="12" Margin="8,37,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding StartDate.Year}" FontSize="12" Margin="37,37,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="28" FontSize="12" Height="Auto" Margin="85,12,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource Lato-Semibold}" Text="{Binding PastDayOfWeekString}"/>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" Margin="75,33,0,0" Height="Auto" Style="{DynamicResource Lato-Semibold}" Text="{Binding PastHourString}"/>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" Margin="91,33,0,0" Height="Auto" Style="{DynamicResource Lato-Semibold}" Text=":"/>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" Margin="95,33,0,0" Height="Auto" Style="{DynamicResource Lato-Semibold}" Text="{Binding PastMinuteString}"/>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Subject}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Margin="20,14,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Subject}" FontSize="13" Margin="20,33,0,0"/>
                                <Image Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{Binding Presence, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Grid.Column="1" Source="/Resources/Images/icon-presence.png" Margin="0,0,7,0" Width="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Image> 
                            </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </surface:SurfaceButton>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved in this way :

1 - download from NuGet ***Microsoft.Surface*** : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Surface/

2 - add the assembly to the xaml :

```
xmlns:surface = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"
```

3 - change the ***ScrollViewer*** with ***surface:SurfaceScrollViewer***

updated code with SurfaceScrollViewer :

```
<surface:SurfaceScrollViewer x:Name="listPastMeetinsVisibility" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="15,36,15,35" Background="GhostWhite" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" PanningMode="Both">
          <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PastMeetingList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <Button Tag="{Binding MID}" Click="Meeting_Click">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <StackPanel>                        
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="118"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderBrush="#DDD" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"></Border>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="28" Margin="20,5,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource Lato-Semibold}" Text="{Binding PastDayString}"/>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding PastMonthString}" FontSize="12" Margin="8,37,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding StartDate.Year}" FontSize="12" Margin="37,37,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="28" FontSize="12" Height="Auto" Margin="85,12,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource Lato-Semibold}" Text="{Binding PastDayOfWeekString}"/>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" Margin="75,33,0,0" Height="Auto" Style="{DynamicResource Lato-Semibold}" Text="{Binding PastHourString}"/>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" Margin="91,33,0,0" Height="Auto" Style="{DynamicResource Lato-Semibold}" Text=":"/>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" Margin="95,33,0,0" Height="Auto" Style="{DynamicResource Lato-Semibold}" Text="{Binding PastMinuteString}"/>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Subject}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Margin="20,14,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Subject}" FontSize="13" Margin="20,33,0,0"/>
                                <Image Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{Binding Presence, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Grid.Column="1" Source="/Resources/Images/icon-presence.png" Margin="0,0,7,0" Width="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Image> 
                            </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          </ItemsControl>
        </surface:SurfaceScrollViewer>
```

Enjoy the Stylus pen on surface scrollviewer :)